# Trouble proving natural number inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+m}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{1+n}} \ge 1$

Tags: inequality, radicals

I came across an inequality and I can't seem to solve it.

> For all natural numbers $m, n$,
>
> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+m}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{1+n}} \ge 1.$$

I tried isolating roots and then raise both sides to power of `m` (or `n`) but that didn't lean anywhere.

Can anyone show me what would be the way to go about this?

Comment: For all natural numbers $m$, $n$?

Comment: yes. I forgot to add that

Comment: @6005 isn't there a `$\forall$`?

Comment: Yes, there is. However, when typing math it is almost always clearer to write it out in English unless you are isolating a specific quantified formula.

Comment: maybe use induction?

Comment: I see, thanks! Now all I have left is waiting for an answer... I'm new here (as you probably noticed) so I don't know how long it usually takes for people to answer

Comment: @Mastrem - tried that, I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: Oh okay, well I'll go and try some (other) things out then.

Comment: @Mastrem thank you very much :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of radicals greater than 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467607/sum-of-radicals-greater-than-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** By [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+m}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{1+n}} \geqslant \frac1{1+m/n}+ \frac1{1+n/m} = 1$$

Comment: +1 ... Bernoulli's Inequality is one of those undervalued treasures.

Comment: @macavity : Is this true for all integers  ? $$\sqrt2=\sqrt{1+1}\\n=2,m=1 \to \\\sqrt{1+1}\geq 1+\frac12=1.5\\\sqrt2=1.41\geq 1.5$$ How it's possible  ?

Comment: @Khosrotash  you have the inequality the wrong way round. For any natural $n,m$ we have $\sqrt[n]{1+m}\leqslant 1+m/n$. So when you take reciprocals, the inequality reverses.